# Avoid passing empty arrays/variables in $http

Tags: angularjs

Newbie here. I have an AngularJS form in which users can fill in optional form values (for a real-life example, users can provide friends with up to 5 book recommendations and up to 5 music recommendations). I initialize the form with empty values:

```
var master = {
type: 'recommendations',
books:[
  {name:'', description :''},
  {name:'', description :''},
  {name:'', description :''},
  {name:'', description :''},
  {name:'', description :''}
],
music:[
  {name:'', description :''},
  {name:'', description :''},
  {name:'', description :''},
  {name:'', description :''},
  {name:'', description :''}
],
};
```

Is there any way to easily trim off any empty elements of each array before passing $scope.form in $http.post? I'd prefer not to have to check whether each element is empty in the script that processes the JSON.

Comment: By empty element, you mean, empty object literals: "{}", or object elements with "name" and/or "description" === "" or undefined?  Do you want help looping through the elements of your parent object there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup an [interceptor](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) to do any transformation needed before actually posting to the server

Example of global transformRequest:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data){
        //here you can do any transformation needed to the request
        return cleanData(data);
    }
});
```